# Hire Car in Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a question to make a programme for Car Hiring Company. I am stuck in few questions and not sure about some of my answers, so I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

First question:

A hire car is sent for service when it returns from hire if the number of miles it has been driven since its last service has reached (or exceeded) its service interval.

HireCar should include the following two private methods

1. a boolean method serviceDue to determine whether this HireCar is due a service
2. a method sendForService

For the first one I wrote:

```
private boolean serviceDue() {
  if (mileage - lastService >= serviceInterval)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Is this code right? For the second one I don't think I get what the question wants me to do, any tips would be great. I wrote the same code as in number 1 except that I changed ServiceDue to SendForService, is it right ?

Any help would be great, thank you very much.

Comment: What is `sendForService()` supposed to do?  There's no way to know if your implementation is correct without knowing the requirements regarding that method.

Comment: Sorry my bad, look at the new edit

Comment: I tried this code and I think it's better,, public boolean serviceDue(){
        return mileage - lastService >= serviceInterval;
    }

Comment: So both methods do the same thing/ serve the same purpose? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: yeah that's why I am not sure about the second because it makes no sense to have the same code twice unless I misunderstood it.

Comment: That's the complete description of the problem given?

Comment: If the entire requirement is only that a method named "sendForService" exists, you don't need any code in it.  `public void sendForService() {}` would suffice.  That seems unlikely, though.  Are you *sure* there isn't more to this problem?

Comment: Yeah there is nothing more, should I just write,, public void sendForService() {}  ??

Comment: I'd say so or ask your instructor or whomever created the problem for clarification?

Comment: I second the "ask the teacher" recommendation.  The problem as stated makes no sense.  Rather than guessing what the intention is, it's better to ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help guys, is there any way I can contact any of you in private if it's ok if I needed more help as I take this module for one year and it's not my speciality and I get stuck with a lot of stuff, that would be great and thank you very much again

Comment: can you please look at the second question and see if you can help I just edited it